# How to access a service deployed as NodePort in Minikube in EC2 from outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have installed minikube in EC2 Linux Instance.

```
Minikube IP : 192.168.49.2, 
EC2 Instance IP: 10.X.X.X
```

I've deployed an application as NodePort service type where

```
port: 80
targetPort: 80
nodePort: 32768
and able to access it with curl http://192.168.49.2:32768 within the cluster.
```

How should I expose this application to the outside world?
If port forwarding is the option then I tried the below ways:

```
kubectl port-forward --address <InstanceIP> svc/my-service 8888:80
```

This always gives error:

```
Unable to listen on port 5000: 
Listeners failed to create with the following errors: 
[unable to create listener] error: 
unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{8888 80}]
```

I made sure there is no service running on port 8888.

```
kubectl port-forward --address <InstanceIP> svc/my-service 8888:32768
```

This says, error:

```
Service my-service does not have a service port 32768.
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I expose this application to the outside world?

You should use a `Service` with a `type: LoadBalancer`

`LoadBalancer` will give you an External Ip that will allow you to connect to it from outside the cluster.

If you only need it for testing and this is why you are using `minikube` then port forward should cover the requirements.

#### Using `LoadBalancer` with `minikube`

In order to use `LoadBalanacer` with minikube you should open a new terminal and execute `minikube tunnel`

```
# Port forward to the desired service, 
# dont forget to add the namespace if any

#
# You should forward to port 80 which is the port defined in your service
#     port : 80
#     targetPort : 80
kubectl port-forward svc/my-service 8888:80 -n <namespace>

# As you mentioned you tried it already and it's not working
# so follow below and try to expose your service with

kubectl expose
```

Now you should be able to connect to your service.

---

Here is a full example which generates `Service`

https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/02-Deployments-Imperative

The sample generates the `Service` on the fly with

```
kubectl expose deployment -n codewizard multitool --port 80 --type NodePort
```